# C# Load a .NET assembly from memory with parameters

Tags: c#

I would like to know how i can launch a .NET assembly from a byte array with parameters. I do not want to write it to the disk first. Could anyone give me an example on how to do this? Thank you.

Comment: If your assembly is of type `exe`. You cannot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
Assembly program = Assembly.Load(ASSEMBLY_BYTES);

string[] args = new string[] { "-s" };

program.EntryPoint.Invoke(null, new object[] { args });
```

Comment: +1 ...and that's a pretty old trick http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13897/Load-an-EXE-File-and-Run-It-from-Memory - and some more info

Answer (score 1):

There is a [method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa329934%28v=vs.71%29.aspx): `Assembly.Load(Byte[])`.

Comment: well, his assembly is a executable file, and he needs to start it with certain command-line parameters, so i guess its not possible.

Comment: The problem with this is that i can not give any arguments to the program

Answer (score 0):

I asked the question on another forum and they were able to help me, this is what i was looking for;

```
        Assembly program = Assembly.Load(ASSEMBLY_BYTES);

        string[] args = new string[] { "-s" };

        program.EntryPoint.Invoke(null, new object[] { args });
```